# Fragment hides drawer menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

The onViewCreate method of Chapter1Fragment class (extending from android.app.Fragment) is returning an object of a class which is subclass of android.opengl.GLSurfaceView

This fragment appears fine on the activity. But the problem is that the drawer navigation view does hides behind this fragment. Please suggest how the drawer menu can be fixed?

here is the code of onViewCreate

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int chapterNumber = 1;
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.txt_chap1);
    mPageFlipView = new PageFlipView(getActivity(), chapterNumber);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), this);

    mPageFlipView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mPageFlipView.onFingerUp(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
                return true;
            }

            return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    });
    return mPageFlipView;
}
```

There is another Fragment HomeFragment which invokes the following code to make Chapter1Fragment appear

```
Chapter1Fragment fragment = new Chapter1Fragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Here is the xml file that is passed to setContentView() of MainActivity's onCreate()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the app_bar_main.xml from layout directory

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="viento.com.bookapp.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the content_main.xml from layout directory

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
/>
```

[image: screen shot of the fragment hiding the navigation drawer menu]

Comment: Could you show the XML as well?

Comment: That's an xml problem. Write you fragment container after the drawer, or drawer after fragment container.

Comment: I have now added the xml too

Comment: Where's your `NavigationView` tag located?

Comment: @Mauker I added three xml files. Please see the first one. It contains NavigationView

Comment: @Mauker  Actually the main activity was creating using Activity Creation Wizard of Android Studio. I selected Navigation Drawer Activity in the wizard. I am using Android Studio version 3.0.1

Comment: Now I saw it, sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Mauker Please let me know if you see any issue. By the way, can you suggest me a way to invoke tap on Drawer Navigation Item, programmatically. I think that can be a work around.